# UFW & VPN : How to allow reconnection

Tags: vpn, firewall, ufw

Here are the rules of my firewall :

```
deny outgoing
deny incoming
allow out from any to any on tun0 (alow just the traffic from the VPN)
```

However, I am forced to disable ufw when I want to start my vpn connection from gnome-network manager.
Yet, I tried something like :

```
allow out from any to any on wlan0 port 1194
```

But it does not work.

Any suggestions ?

SOLUTION :

Those following lines enable you to block all the outgoing NON-VPN traffic. In other words, only the VPN traffic is allowed.
Besides, in case your VPN connection failed, you will be able to reconnect without disabling your firewall.

1 - Run the following command in a terminal :

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
```

2 - Try to connect to your VPN

3 - Look at all the  "[UFW BLOCK]"'s lines with an Ip adress
In my case, I have two adress ip with DST=***.***.**.240 and DST="**.**.**.241.

Then I have the Ip given by my VPN which is also blocked.

3 - Allow those ip in your firewall  :

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
***.**.**.240              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
***.**.**.241              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
**.***.0.0/18  (VPN)            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
22/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on `port 1194` I guess you use OpenVPN.
OpenVpn documentation in the FAQ recommended fallowing

> Which ports do I need to open in my firewall for Access Server?
>
> Short answer: TCP 443, TCP 943, UDP 1194 Long answer: By default
>   OpenVPN Access Server has 2 OpenVPN daemons running. One of them on
>   UDP port 1194 and another on TCP 443. We recommend that you use the
>   UDP port because this functions better for an OpenVPN tunnel. However,
>   many public locations block all sorts of ports except very common ones
>   like http, https, ftp, pop3, and so on. Therefore we also have TCP 443
>   as an option. TCP port 443 is the default port for https:// (SSL)
>   traffic and so this is usually allowed through at the user's location.
>   TCP port 943 is the port where the web server interface is listening
>   by default. You can either approach this directly using a URL like
>   https://yourserverhostnamehere:943/ or by approaching it through the
>   standard https:// port TCP 443, since the OpenVPN daemon will
>   automatically internally route browser traffic to TCP 943 by default.
>   (https://yourserverhostnamehere/).

But my recommendation, from battle field, is to allow all traffic from vpn server ip address

```
sudo ufw allow from ip_address_of_vpn_server
```

Do not specify proto because OpenVPN use both, `tcp` and `udp`

Edit 1

Also you can create script to auto reconnect when `tun0` is `down`.

Add a simple script to caled `tun-up`in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` which content is

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename: tun-up

if [ "$IFACE" = tun0 ]; then
  sudo ifup tun0
fi
```

make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/tun-up
```

Edit 2

Ok, we allow wrong address.
First we need to catch correct ip address to allow traffic.

Start `terminal` and run command

```
tail -f /var/log/system | grep UFW
```

then try to connect to vpn sever. In terminal you will see block off

```
May 25 08:18:22 xxx kernel: [259789.025019] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:23:cd:f4:8c:29:08:00 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

In block find `SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`, this is address who send traffic to you, in most cases this will be public ip address of vpn server.

This ip address must add in `ufw` rules on first please, because you talk and exchange traffic with this address before is `tun0` up.

Rule is

```
sudo ufw insert 1 allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Comment: Thanks but how to set set a range of ip ?


My VPN provides a random ip between  00.000.32.0 and 00.000.63.255.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow from xx.xxx.32.0/18` This rule is for net range you are specified,

Comment: You have my `edit 1` in answer to make auto reconnect of `tun0`

Comment: Thanks again 2707974.
However, it is not working.

Can you take a look at my `Edit 1` please ?

Comment: The VPN connection failed (I must still shutdown the firewall)

Comment: I add Edit 2 in answer

Comment: Thanks again. 
I got my local ip adress and DST=***.**.****

See my `EDIT 2`

Comment: Ok, you must allow your PC to go to the VPN server without routing to `tun0` interface because `tun0` is still down. Make rule and put then on the first place `sudo ufw insert 1 allow out from any to DST_ip_address`. This will be solution.

Comment: It Is working ! You can take a look at `Solution".

Any idea what does DST=""  mean ?

Comment: I guess the DST ip are for the DNS

Comment: Dst is destination ip address. Probably ip of you vpn server

Comment: It is the 2 IP of the DNS server of my ISP. 
If I remove those 2 rules in UFW, it is not working.